# calling TaskDialogIndirect loader says ordinal 345 not found

Tags: windows, windows-vista, taskdialog

I built the simple MS example for TaskDialogIndirect (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760544(v=vs.85).aspx)

When I run it I get "The ordinal 345 could not be located in the dynamic link library COMCTL32.dll"

The above page says it needs ComCtl32.DLL version 6 but C:\Windows\System32\ComCtl32.DLL is 5.82.7601.18201 and I can't find a version 6 anywhere on the disk.

I am running Windows 7 with VS2012. TaskDialog was added in Vista so why don't I have the correct version of ComCtl32.DLL???

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a common and useful block of code that should help to load the correct *common controls*, `comctl32.dll`:

```
#if defined _M_IX86
#pragma comment(linker, "/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#elif defined _M_IA64
#pragma comment(linker, "/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='ia64' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#elif defined _M_X64
#pragma comment(linker, "/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='amd64' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#else
#pragma comment(linker, "/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#endif
```

Answer (score 5):

There are two versions of ComCtl32.dll on Windows XP and later ([SxS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side-by-side_assembly)). v5.8x is the default, you need to opt-in to get v6 because of possible incompatibility's with the new Themes/Visual Styles. Most new features and controls have only been added to v6.

To get v6 you must [add a manifest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175(v=vs.85).aspx#no_extensions) to your application. It is recommended that you embed the manifest in the applications resources but you can also use a external manifest; just name the XML file `yourappname.exe.manifest`.

Comment: Thank you! I was pulling my hair out trying to figure out what the heck was going on and which library it was that "ordinal 345" was referring to, but in the end this was the solution. ‍♂️

Answer (score -4):

You can run `sfc /scannow` to resolve this issue. [[Reference](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/the-ordinal-345-could-not-be-located-in-dinamyc-li/134186#T-N139816)].