# Running programs using RtlCreateUserProcess only works occasionally

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, nt-native-api

Disclaimer: This questions seems to get downvoted because I should use the normal Win32 API (CreateProcess, ShellExecute). I know about these APIs and I'm aware that `RtlCreateUserProcess` is not supposed to be called directly. However, the native API is a very relevant topic regarding security, that's why I am researching it.

I'm trying to run programs on Windows using the function `RtlCreateUserProcess`, exported from ntdll.dll. My code works to run calc.exe, however, after trying to run notepad.exe, I receive an error message that reads `The ordinal 345 could not be located in dynamic link library "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\notepad.exe"`. When trying to run other programs it displays various similar messages, always related to some ordinals or DLLs missing.

My example code looks like this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <winternl.h>

typedef struct _SECTION_IMAGE_INFORMATION {

    PVOID                   EntryPoint;
    ULONG                   StackZeroBits;
    ULONG                   StackReserved;
    ULONG                   StackCommit;
    ULONG                   ImageSubsystem;
    WORD                    SubSystemVersionLow;
    WORD                    SubSystemVersionHigh;
    ULONG                   Unknown1;
    ULONG                   ImageCharacteristics;
    ULONG                   ImageMachineType;
    ULONG                   Unknown2[3];

} SECTION_IMAGE_INFORMATION, * PSECTION_IMAGE_INFORMATION;

typedef struct _RTL_USER_PROCESS_INFORMATION {

    ULONG                   Size;
    HANDLE                  ProcessHandle;
    HANDLE                  ThreadHandle;
    CLIENT_ID               ClientId;
    SECTION_IMAGE_INFORMATION ImageInformation;

} RTL_USER_PROCESS_INFORMATION, * PRTL_USER_PROCESS_INFORMATION;

typedef VOID(NTAPI* Func1)(PUNICODE_STRING DestinationString, __drv_aliasesMem PCWSTR SourceString);
typedef NTSTATUS(NTAPI* Func2)(OUT PRTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS* pProcessParameters, IN PUNICODE_STRING ImagePathName, IN PUNICODE_STRING DllPath OPTIONAL, IN PUNICODE_STRING CurrentDirectory OPTIONAL, IN PUNICODE_STRING CommandLine OPTIONAL, IN PVOID Environment OPTIONAL, IN PUNICODE_STRING WindowTitle OPTIONAL, IN PUNICODE_STRING DesktopInfo OPTIONAL, IN PUNICODE_STRING ShellInfo OPTIONAL, IN PUNICODE_STRING RuntimeData OPTIONAL);
typedef NTSTATUS(NTAPI* Func3)(PUNICODE_STRING NtImagePathName, ULONG Attributes, PRTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS ProcessParameters, PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR ProcessSecurityDescriptor, PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR ThreadSecurityDescriptor, HANDLE ParentProcess, BOOLEAN InheritHandles, HANDLE DebugPort, HANDLE ExceptionPort, PRTL_USER_PROCESS_INFORMATION ProcessInformation);

int main()
{

    UNICODE_STRING str;

    PRTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS processparameters; 
    RTL_USER_PROCESS_INFORMATION processinformation = { 0 }; 

    Func1 RtlInitUnicodeString = (Func1)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleW(L"ntdll.dll"), "RtlInitUnicodeString");
    Func2 RtlCreateProcessParameters = (Func2)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleW(L"ntdll.dll"), "RtlCreateProcessParameters");
    Func3 RtlCreateUserProcess = (Func3)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleW(L"ntdll.dll"), "RtlCreateUserProcess");

    RtlInitUnicodeString(&str, L"\\??\\C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\notepad.exe"); //Starting calc.exe works, notepad.exe does not.
    RtlCreateProcessParameters(&processparameters, &str, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    NTSTATUS works = RtlCreateUserProcess(&str, OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE, processparameters, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, NULL, NULL, &processinformation);
    
    if (NT_SUCCESS(works)) {
        ResumeThread(processinformation.ThreadHandle);
        //Started application crashes at this point + the error message gets shown
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Failed" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, there is not much information available about using this function, so I would appreciate any answers on how to use this function correctly.

Comment: Why are you using `RtlCreateUserProcess` at all?  `CreateProcess` (or, for its added functional, `ShellExecute`) is the 'official' way to do it.

Comment: I'm well aware of the Win32 API, but this is more meant as a research project in a red teaming and security context.

Comment: *The ordinal 345 could not be located in dinamyc link library* - really in *ComCtl32.DLL* pre 6 version (5.82). 345 - this is `TaskDialogIndirect` api which exist only in *ComCtl32.DLL* version 6+. but your process load 5.82.. - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37016803/calling-taskdialogindirect-loader-says-ordinal-345-not-found

Comment: different begin from - if process created with `CreateProcess` - it do more compare `RtlCreateUserProcess` - in particular it create activation context for new process based on exe manifest ( `PEB.ActivationContextData` not 0 in new process) but `RtlCreateUserProcess` not create activation context. as result `ComCtl32.dll` will be or not redirected to 6+ version. *TaskDialogIndirect (345)* exist in one and not exist in another..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CreateProcess` after create new process do much more job, in particular it create activation context for new process based on exe manifest (`BasepConstructSxsCreateProcessMessage` + `CsrClientCallServer`) as result new process have initial activation context, stored in `PEB` (*SystemDefaultActivationContextData* and *ActivationContextData*) but in process created with pure call to `RtlCreateUserProcess` this fields is empty (0). as result your process loaded *ComCtl32.dll* from *system32* (version *5.82* ) and notepad with activation context - *6+* version.

> The ordinal 345 could not be located in dynamic link library

really in *ComCtl32.DLL* pre *6* version (*5.82*). `345` - this is `TaskDialogIndirect` api which exist only in *ComCtl32.DLL* version *6+*. but your process load *5.82*.. - [*calling TaskDialogIndirect loader says ordinal 345 not found*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37016803/calling-taskdialogindirect-loader-says-ordinal-345-not-found)

so `CreateProcess` not a thin shell over `RtlCreateUserProcess` or `NtCreateUserProcess`, but big and complex api. at it functional very hard if possible at all implement direct

Comment: Moral of the story: if you're studying this for security research purposes, launch your own stripped-down binaries.